# .Net DateTime() to Date using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime

I am getting the Date value as DateTime from code behind to my javascript. I have to handle it in javascript only, below is the string I am currently getting from code behind to my Client side.

```
"Mon Oct 05 2015 13:34:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

How to change this string to Date only from javascript. I want the format as "`dd/mm/yyyy`".

Comment: Did you look at all? There are literally hundreds of these questions answered here - start with this: `new Date(Date.parse("Mon Oct 05 2015 13:34:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"))`

Comment: @mplungjan yes found the solution. Thank you for the path.

Comment: If you want it to be in `dd/mm/yyyy` then why not specifically format it like that from the server side DateTime object, rather than dealing with the abnormally long string you're using now?

Comment: @mason we are getting the data from web service and we dont have control on that service so we have to handle from our side. I have mentioned it also "I have to handle it in javascript only".

Comment: Your question title states that it's ".Net DateTime". Why would you state that if it's not relevant to the question?

Comment: @mason Its a .Net WCF service which gives us the Data. why "-1" ?????

Comment: Then it's not relevant to the question. If you have zero control over the service, then mentioning whether it's a .NET DateTime object, or the equivalent in Java, Ruby on Rails, PHP etc is not relevant. Stating irrelevant things throws the question off. Perhaps you should correct your title to state what you're actually trying to accomplish, such as "How do I convert a string to a Date in JavaScript"? Of course, as mplungjan points out, that has been asked plenty of times.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xL5rdce9/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var day = moment("Mon Oct 05 2015 13:34:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change it server side, then start here:

```js
alert(new Date(Date.parse("Mon Oct 05 2015 13:34:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)")))
```

then according to your own answer, you can end up here:

```js
function pad(num) {
    return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
var myCSharpString = "Mon Oct 05 2015 13:34:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
var date = new Date(Date.parse(myCSharpString));
alert(pad(date.getUTCDate()) + "/" + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for dates.

```js
var format = moment("Mon Oct 05 2015 13:34:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
alert(new Date(format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Just got the solution.

below is the javascript code taking argument as the .Net DateTime() string

```
function formatTheDate(strDate) {
    if (strDate != '') {
        var date = new Date(Date.parse(strDate));
        var formatedDate = (date.getUTCDate()) + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        return formatedDate;
    }
}
```

fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/xL5rdce9/